# In Angularjs - When are parent scope variables available to the child?

Tags: angularjs

I have a one page app. When the parent controller loads it retrieves data from an API and puts it in `$scope.APIData` and then this data loads it is available to the child controller.

When I change the state the new child seems to not immediately be aware of the parent `$scope.APIData` and is blank when evaluated. However if I put a watch on it, it will update a split second later.

Is there (or can there be) a delay when a child is loading before it has access to the parent `$scope` or should I look else where to solve my problem?

Comment: Are you trying to access `$scope.APIData` when the child controller initializes? If so, I assume this is caused because `$scope.APIData` gets populated asynchronously. Some code snippets can help to understand the problem better.

Comment: @Quiriacus Yes I am trying to access when the child controller initializes however the data is being populated asynchronously when the Parent loads - so I thought would be immediately available to the child. When the child state changes I will get a `$scope.APIData.variable1` is not defined in the console on initialization but it will update a split second later.

Comment: Ah - it seems that my parent is reloading!! I don't know why yet but I put `console.log('parent loaded')` in the parent controller and sure enough when the child state changes the parent reloads. Most likely something is wrong with my routes.